# Getting two largest numbers from three numbers without using conditional statement or loop in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Complete the `function1()` function which is passed three whole
>   numbers.The function returns the total of the two bigger numbers.

```
print()
print(1, function1(1, 2, 3))
print(2, function1(11, 12, 3))
print(3, function1(6, 2, 5))

output should be 
1 5
2 23
3 11
```

This was the question. I try googling but all I have found was using conditional
statement or loop. I was wondering if there is other way to do this without using both? Reason being is that this question was on before the introduction of conditional statement and loop. I can advance my self-studying and do it however 
there must be a reason why it poped up before we go onto the next chapter. 
What do you reckon?..   (During self-studying for CS101) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could sort the tuple of the numbers and add the first 2 values:

```
def function1(a, b, c):
    s = sorted((a, b, c), reverse=True)
    return s[0] + s[1]
```

`sorted` starts with the smalles item normally that's why you need to set `reverse=True`.

or you could sum the three and subtract the minimal value:

```
def function1(a, b, c):
    return sum((a, b, c)) - min(a, b, c)
```

Comment: I think he's looking for the 2nd solution since sorting still uses a loop somewhere in it.

Comment: Well, `sum` has an implicit loop in it too. And `min` has an implicit conditional. Like most exercise problems with artificial restrictions, this one is ill-defined.

Comment: @tzaman that is correct. but there is no way around that... so the problem should be stated 'without using `if` and `for`'?

Comment: Yes, that's why I hate this sort of made up exercise. And if it's just without `if` and `for` then either of your solutions works.

Comment: Thank you hiro protagonist ! didnt think of it as a mathematical way at all !! I can totally use the second method since those in-built fuctions were learned already. Cheers !